# show free space on a gvfs mount?

Tags: storage, gvfs, free

How can I check the free space on a gvfs mounted partition.
I want to use it on a script.

mounted with
 `gvfs-mount "ftp://192.168.178.**/Disk-01/"`

df does not provide usefull data:

`gvfsd-fuse                      0         0         0    - /run/user/1000/gvfs`

The free space line is missing:

```
`gvfs-info -f /run/user/1000/gvfs/ftp:host=192.168.178.**/Disk-01/`
```

`attributes:
  filesystem::type: ftp
  gvfs::backend: ftp`

Comment: How did you mount the gvfs device?

Comment: @ L. D. James: i added the command